# Listbox bound to an ObservableCollection doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, binding

I am using a ObservableCollection to store the Environment Variables of Windows.

```
class VariableVieWModel
{
    ObservableCollection<VariableModel> vars;

    public ObservableCollection<VariableModel> Variables
    {
        get
        {
            return vars;
        }
        set
        {
            vars = value;
        }
    }

    public VariableViewModel() 
    {
        Reload();
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
    // Code to retrieve vars
    }
}
```

This ObservableCollection is bound to a ListBox.

I have added a button in the GUI to reload the Variables whichi, on click, it calls the Reload() procedure.

ListBox content, however, does not change and I cannot add anymore items to the list afer calling Reload().

Under the constructor everything is working fine.

ListBox XAML :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbVariables" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource variablesViewModel}, Path=Variables}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

I tried using also PropertyChanged as UpdateSource trigger and set most of the Modes.

```
public void Reload()
    {
        vars = new ObservableCollection<VariableModel>();

        RegistryKey systemVarKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment");

        string[] systemVars = systemVarKey.GetValueNames();

        foreach (string var in systemVars)
        {
            vars.Add(new VariableModel()
            {
                Name = var,
                Values = (systemVarKey.GetValue(var, null, RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames) as string).Split(';').ToList<string>(),
                Target = EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine
            });
        } 
        systemVarKey.Close();

        RegistryKey userVarKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Environment");

        string[] userVars = userVarKey.GetValueNames();

        foreach (string var in userVars)
        {
            vars.Add(new VariableModel()
            {
                Name = var,
                Values = (userVarKey.GetValue(var, null, RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames) as string).Split(';').ToList<string>(),
                Target = EnvironmentVariableTarget.User
            });
        }
        userVarKey.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your VariableVieWModel to refresh your target object bindings. You just have to do this way -

```
class VariableVieWModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { .
      .
            public ObservableCollection<VariableModel> Variables
            {
               get
               {
                  return vars;
               }
               set
               {
                  if(vars!=value)
                  {
                      vars = value;
                      OnPropertyChanged("Variables");
                  }
               }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      
            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            } 
    }
```

Comment: Should I add something particular to the ListBox Properties?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You just need to call OnPropertyChanged event from your property setter.

Comment: And one more thing you should avoid setting the same value for the property as it will unnecessarily raise the property change event. Just a good practise for writing a property.

Comment: I have implemented your code, however i cannot see any changes in the ListBox

Comment: There might be something wrong with your listbox or Reload method. Can you paste your code here?

Comment: If VariablesViewModel is datacontext of your usercontrol than you should set it as datacontext in your usercontrol's constructor in your codebehind instead of declaring it as a StaticResource in your xaml file.

Comment: Because StaticResource is defined at the time of UI rendering which will insatantiate VariablesViewModel object and i doubt you are also calling constructor of VariablesViewModel explicitly from code which will create two instances for a same class.

Comment: Also in you Reload method, everytime you are re-instantiating the vars object. Instead of doing this just take a local method object(say localvars), fill it and then set the local object to your property like this - 'Variables = localvars;'

Answer (score 3):

You haven't modified the ObservableCollection, only replaced it.
You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `PropertyChanged` in the `Variables` property setter.

BTW it's common in MVVM implementations to have a base class for your ViewModel:

```
class VariableViewModel : ViewModelBase
```

and implement common functionality such as `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the base class to avoid duplication of code.

Comment: +1 Sorry, I have accidentally edited your post! Please look if I have restored it correctyl.

Comment: It's correnct... Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a try.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that probably your VariableModel does not implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). Through ObservableCollection, only changes to the collection are reported, not changes of the contained objects.

[Here](http://www.pochet.net/blog/2010/06/25/inotifypropertychanged-implementations-an-overview/) you will find some implementation possibilities.

Comment: This helped me as from all examples I seemed to be doing everything right. The only way I could get the ItemsSource of the ListBox to update when a property changed on a contained object was to handler the PropertyChanged event on the control/window hosting the ListBox  <br/>  </br>void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e){  <br/>    MyListBox.Refresh();  <br/>}