# ListView bound to ObservableCollection<T> Doesn't update when Added to property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a File Explorer an when the user DoubleClicks a TreeView it fires this event. Which fills an `ObservableCollection<T>` that is bound to my ListView called `File_List`.the FillCollection method does fill FileList with correct Information .

I have changed this from filling in c# to binding as I think that it will be easier to maintain. Thank you fro your time. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841453/listbox-bound-to-an-observablecollection-doesnt-update) which tells me to impalement `INotifyPropertyChanged` I have that with `RaisedPropertyChanged` method.

```
private void folderItems_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)folderItems.SelectedItem;
        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(item.Tag.ToString());
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            _ViewModel.FileList = FillFileModel.FillCollection(item.Tag.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
           //Do something else
        }

    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

**FillFileModel Class**

```
public static ObservableCollection<Files> FillCollection(string Path)
{
    ObservableCollection<Files> files = new ObservableCollection<Files>();

    var searchDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
    try
    {
        Files getFile;
        foreach (var file in searchDirectory.GetFiles())
        {
            getFile = new Files
            {
                FileName = file.Name,
                FileSize = file.Length.ToString("#,##0 KB"),
                DateModified = file.LastWriteTime,
                FileType = getFileType(file.FullName)
            };

            files.Add(getFile);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return files;
}
```

**the bound property:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Files> FileList
{
    get { return _FileList; }
    set
    {
        if (_FileList!=value)
        {
            _FileList = value;
            RaisedPropertyChanged("FileList");
        }
    }
}
```

**RaisedPropertyChanged**

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void RaisedPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, args);
    }
}


**XAML:**
<Window.Resources>
    <uc:ucNav x:Key="Nav"/>        
    <uc:FileExplorerViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    <local:FileImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

 <ListView Width="580" Margin="205,32,9,10" x:Name="File_List" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Name" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Height="20" Width="20" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="file_Name" Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150">
                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <TextBlock Text="Date Modified" />
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Date_Modified"  Text="{Binding DateModified}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150">
                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <TextBlock Text="File Type" />
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="File_Type" Text="{Binding FileType}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="130">
                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <TextBlock Text="File Size" />
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="File_Size" Text="{Binding FileSize}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listbox bound to an ObservableCollection doesn't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841453/listbox-bound-to-an-observablecollection-doesnt-update)

Comment: Do you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your ViewModel class in addition to the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: yes I add that under RaisedPropertyChanged

Comment: Did you set the XAML DataContext to your viewmodel?

Comment: I will edit Xmal. please review, and make sure this is correct.

Comment: What happens when you set breakpoints? What part of your event chain does not work?

Comment: In addition to using breakpoints to verify your code is running correctly, I'd also recommend using a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to verify your DataContext is set correctly

Comment: that's the thing, it all seams to work.

Comment: @JamTay317 My main guesses would be either DataContext is set incorrectly, incorrect code to load collection, or code is running on a background thread or other dispatcher queue, which can cause property changed to not raise UI update properly. I am still a bit unclear about what exactly is failing here. Is your ListView failing to load when you double-click an item in your treeview? And can you verify that the breakpoints show the list is being populated, and it is the correct DataContext?

Comment: @Rachel Yes it is failing to load. but when i change from binding to observableCollection to seting ItemSorce to the observableCollection it loads.

Comment: Did you test my answer?   Notify on a collection as a whole does not work.

Comment: @JamTay317 My best guess then is that your DataContext is incorrect. Place a breakpoint in the double-click event handler and test that `File_List.DataContext == _ViewModel`. The most likely problem here is that it's not. Alternatively, you can try downloading something like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to get a better look at your visual tree and data, and try to debug it from there.

Comment: @Rachel this worked!

Comment: @Frisbee, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: FileList.Add(   If the comment from Rachel worked go with it

Comment: @JamTay317 Glad that worked for you :) I posted it as an answer below as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your DataContext is not set correctly, as the other code you have posted looks correct.

Place a breakpoint in your click handler and double-check that `File_List.DataContext == _ViewModel`

The `DataContext` is typically inherited from a parent control, or it can be set from the code-behind if this is the top-most window. In rare cases you can also bind or set the value, but this is typically not recommended as it can lead to confusion and debugging headaches.